# Upgrade asdf in sbcl failed

Tags: common-lisp, upgrade, sbcl, asdf

I am failed to upgrade the asdf to version 3 as the page https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf.html#Replacing-your-implementation_0027s-ASDF said

Is there anything wrong with my environment?

CL-USER> (load "/Users/james/Documents/workdir/lisp/source/asdf/tools/install-asdf.lisp")

failed to find the TRUENAME of /usr/local/lib/sbcl/contrib/:
  No such file or directory
   [Condition of type SB-INT:SIMPLE-FILE-ERROR]

#### Restarts:

> 0: [RETRY] Retry EVAL of current toplevel form.
>
> 1:[CONTINUE] Ignore error and continue loading file
>   "/Users/james/Documents/workdir/lisp/source/asdf/tools/install-asdf.lisp".
>
> 2: [ABORT] Abort loading file
>   "/Users/james/Documents/workdir/lisp/source/asdf/tools/install-asdf.lisp".
>
> 3: [RETRY] Retry SLIME REPL evaluation request.
>
> 4: [*ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.
>
> 5: [REMOVE-FD-HANDLER] Remove #

#### Backtrace:

> 0: (SB-IMPL::SIMPLE-FILE-PERROR "failed to find the TRUENAME of ~A" #P"/usr/local/lib/sbcl/contrib/" 2)
>
> 1: ((FLET SB-IMPL::FAIL :IN SB-IMPL::QUERY-FILE-SYSTEM) "failed to find the TRUENAME of ~A" #P"/usr/local/lib/sbcl/contrib/" 2)
>
> 2: (SB-IMPL::QUERY-FILE-SYSTEM #P"/usr/local/lib/sbcl/contrib/" :TRUENAME T)
>
> 3: (TRUENAME #P"/usr/local/lib/sbcl/contrib/")
>
> 4: (ASDF/INTERFACE::MODULE-FASL "uiop")
>
> 5: (ASDF/INTERFACE::INSTALL-UIOP-AND-ASDF-AS-MODULES)
>
> 6: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (ASDF/INTERFACE::INSTALL-UIOP-AND-ASDF-AS-MODULES) #)
>
> 7: (SB-IMPL::SIMPLE-EVAL-PROGN-BODY ((ASDF/INTERFACE::INSTALL-UIOP-AND-ASDF-AS-MODULES) (UIOP/IMAGE:QUIT)) #)
>
> 8: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (PROGN (ASDF/INTERFACE::INSTALL-UIOP-AND-ASDF-AS-MODULES) (UIOP/IMAGE:QUIT)) #)
>
> 9: (EVAL-TLF (PROGN (ASDF/INTERFACE::INSTALL-UIOP-AND-ASDF-AS-MODULES) (UIOP/IMAGE:QUIT)) 14 #)
>
> 10: ((FLET SB-FASL::EVAL-FORM :IN SB-INT:LOAD-AS-SOURCE) (PROGN (ASDF/INTERFACE::INSTALL-UIOP-AND-ASDF-AS-MODULES) (UIOP/IMAGE:QUIT)) 14)
>
> 11: (SB-INT:LOAD-AS-SOURCE # :VERBOSE NIL :PRINT NIL :CONTEXT "loading")
>
> 12: ((FLET SB-FASL::LOAD-STREAM :IN LOAD) # NIL)
>
> 13: (LOAD "/Users/james/Documents/workdir/lisp/source/asdf/tools/install-asdf.lisp" :VERBOSE NIL :PRINT NIL :IF-DOES-NOT-EXIST T :EXTERNAL-FORMAT :DEFAULT)
>
> 14: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (LOAD "/Users/james/Documents/workdir/lisp/source/asdf/tools/install-asdf.lisp") #)
>
> 15: (EVAL (LOAD "/Users/james/Documents/workdir/lisp/source/asdf/tools/install-asdf.lisp"))
>    --more--

Answer (score 0):

How is your SBCL installed?

Did you compile your own SBCL yet fail to use --prefix=... or export INSTALL_ROOT=... when compiling SBCL but not installing it under /usr/local ?

Comment: I installed SBCL by download the lib and call install.sh. The problem is caused by privilege. I started sbcl by root user. There is no such problem again.

Comment: I meet some new errors. Which will cause sbcl exit.
;   redefining COMPONENT-PROPERTY (#<STANDARD-CLASS COMPONENT> #<BUILT-IN-CLASS T>) in DEFMETHOD

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same problem. In my case, it was because I installed sbcl with `brew install sbcl` but failed to notice that brew didn't complete the symlinking stage. `brew link --overwrite sbcl` resolved the problem for me, and it may for you as well.